# SSRS Hiding an Image

Tags: image, reporting-services, visibility

I have a report that requires a logo appear in the header when a certain type of transaction occurs (i.e. Transaction Type A). The problem I'm having is that some receipts have Transaction Type A, but also Transaction Type B and C. In those examples where B and C appear on the receipt it's not pulling the logo even though Transaction Type A is also on the receipt.

Is there anyway to make the hidden statement read so that it looks through each of the transaction on a receipt and presents the logo regardless of if it's just A or A,B,C?

Comment: Is the tablix grouped by the Transaction Type? I'm assuming there is no page break between each instance.. Or does this appear only in the details? Need more information.

Comment: We need to know how the value in your transaction field looks like. A sample table of your fields and a few values would be helpfull.

Comment: visibility of image property. But create a new Dataset and in this your going to check distinct transaction count if any combination has Type_A in it (hint OR condition) you will mark as 1. Then use this dataset as visibility condition. something like (iif check_condition = 1 then ,false,true).